# How can I prevent writing health check requests to nginx access logs in an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently working with an Elastic Beanstalk environment where Nginx is used as the web server. By default, all incoming requests, including health check requests, are being logged in the access logs.

Is there a way to prevent writing health check requests to Nginx access logs specifically in an Elastic Beanstalk environment? I want to keep the access logs informative without cluttering them with health check entries.

Despite using the '.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/location.config' file in this way, health check access logs are still present.

**1. my health check path:** /health

**2. location.config file:**

```
location /health {
        access_log off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }


location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
} 

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

**3.nginx access.log file:**

```
10.0.3.179 - - [26/Nov/2023:12:20:58 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.0.0.6 - - [26/Nov/2023:12:21:07 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.0.3.179 - - [26/Nov/2023:12:21:13 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```